# Scala add number to Future[List[Try[Option[Int]]]]

Tags: scala

I have a variable of type `Future[List[Try[Option[Int]]]]` and i need to add +1 to it.
How i can go through these types without using `compose()` method
Thanks

Comment: You may want to rethink why you end up in that situation. First a **Try** inside a **Future** rarely make sense since **Future** catches exceptions by default. Second, a **List** of **Try** also doesn't make much sense, usually you want a **Try** of a **List**. Finally, a **Try** of an **Option** also can be simplified since the `None` case could be another error.

Comment: This signature is a signal of maybe a bad design somewhere. Try see if you can simplify things before searching to a solution to this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably one possible solution can be:

```
val x = Future.successful(List(Success(Some(1))))

def incr(x: Future[List[Try[Option[Int]]]]): Future[List[Try[Option[Int]]]] = {
  x.map { _.map {
    case Success(Some(num)) => Success(Some(num + 1))
    case other @ _ => other
  }}
}

val res = Await.result(incr(x), Duration.Inf)
println(res) // 2
```

Other one can be:

```
x.map(_.map(_.map(_.map(_ + 1))))
```

If you also want to collect all the relevant values you can for future purpose:

```
val f1 = Future.successful(List(Success(Some(1))))
val f2 = Future.successful(List(Success(Option.empty[Int])))


def incr(future: Future[List[Success[Option[Int]]]]): Future[List[Int]] = {
  future.map { _.collect {
    case Success(Some(num)) => num + 1
  }}
}

assert(Await.result(incr(f1), Duration.Inf).head == 2)
assert(Await.result(incr(f2), Duration.Inf).isEmpty)
```

Comment: "collect" is easier with `flatMap` :) `future.map(_.flatMap(_.toOption.flatMap(_.map(_+1))))`

Answer (score 3):

```
   future.map(_.map(_.map(_.map(_+1))))
```